# Error after installing Civi Entity module

Tags: civicrm-entity

> Blockquote
>   Warning: array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements in CRM_Contact_BAO_Relationship::buildRelationshipTypeOptions() (line 2250 of /home/i571020/membership.irishjudoassociation.ie/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Relationship.php).

I've started getting this error after enabling the module. I can see all the options in views, rules etc. but the warning is visible in the back-end. Is this something in my relationships that's not right or else?

Comment: I see this notice all the time as well....hasn't seemed to cause any problems...I've seen this issue about it too: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/268

Comment: this didn't start appearing until sometime in the 5.x series of CiviCRM as well...

Comment: I've the same issue. Any solution?

Answer (score 3):

Part of the process that CiviCRM Entity uses to integrate is to read metadata on the civicrm API entities, and also for fields with options lists, it fetches those with an API call...
This API call :

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Relationship', 'getoptions', [
  'field' => "relationship_type_id",
]);
```

Is what is producing the warning...

I'm calling this a CiviCRM Core bug/issue..

there is an issue here, I'll update it:
https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/268

Comment: i can work around this issue in CiviCRM Entity, I'll work up a patch for that

Comment: Has this issue ever been resolved, from either end? I'm still seeing this error filling my Drupal logs.

Comment: I don't believe so. I ended up manually updating relationship types, to make sure not exact same names used for 'a' and 'b' in one relationship type. Updating name_a_b or name_b_a didn't seem to have adverse affects .. only if customs look for relationship types specifically by those names.